# How JVM stores the link to enclosing class within inner class?

Tags: java, jvm, inner-classes

Having the following code:

```java
public class Main  {
    private Main() {}

    class Test extends Main {
        {
            System.out.printf("This: %h\nEnclosed in: %h\n", 
                 this, Main.this); 
            System.out.printf("Main.this is instance of %s\n\n" , 
                 Main.this.getClass());
        }
    }

    public static strictfp void main(String... args) {
        new Main().new Test();
    }
}
```

Here are the questions:

1. Were in memory does JVM store the reference Main.this ?

   Is this area (see 1) of memory reserved for normal top-level class instances?

Answer (score 3):

Think of the non-static inner class as something similar to:

```
public class Main {

  static class Test extends Main {
    private final Main _outer;
    ...
  }
}
```

Where the `_outer` reference is established during construction. At the GC level, instances of outer and inner class are not differentiated at all.

Comment: From semantic perpective you're right. I found that there are certain synthetic fields introduced by compiler. I wasn't able to catch those fields with reflection, but i think they are present in the bytecode, i'm not sure how to prove that though

Comment: @Oleksiy: You could use my [Solum](https://github.com/TkTech/Solum) library to do it in a few lines, [like so](https://gist.github.com/0cfd582eab52c8d23b20). :)